# Sprite not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css, sprite

First I have been working on this for way to long :) Have mainly used tutorials to try and get it working, tired searching for an answers but nothing has worked. I have made a sprite with links and it is working ok, but it goes vertical instead of horizontal like I would like. Any help would be amazing!

CSS

```
    .sprite {background:url(/air-head.jpg);no-repeat;margin-left:auto}

    .images {height:68px;}

            .hpa {width:150px; background-position:-2px -2px;display:inline;}
            .co2 {width:150px; background-position:-153px -2px;display:inline;}
            .cover {width:150px; background-position:-304px -2px;display:inline;}
            .reg {width:150px; background-position:-455px -2px;display:inline;}
            .asa {width:150px; background-position:-606px -2px;display:inline;}
            .parts {width:150px; background-position:-757px -2px;display:inline;}
```

HTML

```
<a href="paintball-compressed-air-tanks.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images hpa" alt="Compressed Air Tanks" /></a>
<a href="co2-paintball-tanks.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images co2" alt="Co2 Tanks" /></a>
<a href="paintball-tank-covers-butts.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images cover" alt="Tank" /></a>
<a href="paintball-regulators.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images reg" alt="Paintball Regulators" /></a>
<a href="paintball-tank-accessories.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images asa" alt="Air Accessories" /></a>
<a href="paintball-air-service-parts.html"><img src="/transparent.gif" class="sprite images parts" alt="air system parts" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check your `background-image` and `css` by using http://www.spritecow.com/. It will help you to write proper `position` of images in `sprite`

Answer (score 0):

background-position is defined as `background-position: [vertical offset], [horizontal offset];`. Therefore just invert the offsets:

```
.hpa {width:150px; background-position:-2px -2px;display:inline;}
.co2 {width:150px; background-position:-2px -153px;display:inline;}
.cover {width:150px; background-position:-2px -304px;display:inline;}
.reg {width:150px; background-position:-2px -455px;display:inline;}
.asa {width:150px; background-position:-2px -606px;display:inline;}
.parts {width:150px; background-position:-2px -757px;display:inline;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. After changing the offsets around, the sprite is still vertical and only showing the first portion of the sprite mirroring is down 6 places. http://i.imgur.com/q4VyBXq.jpg